# How to declare twp variables outside of a function

Tags: variables, go

Suppose I want to declare two variables outside of a function in golang, I tried to use the following code

```
var (
    elastic *Client, err error =                
    elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http:145.00.000.01:9600"))
)
```

I got an error saying "unexpected coma, expecting semicolon, new line or ) "

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
var elastic, err  = elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http:145.00.000.01:9600"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize that it is still possible to declare variable using var without using data type.